# Disable the alphabets in JTextField

Tags: java, swing

In html we have:

```
<input type="number">
```

It does not allow the alphabets to be inserted in the field.

Is there any way to do the same with JTextField in Java.

Comment: sure, why not? several ways

Comment: in html we have <input type ="number">

Comment: so? what have you tried so far? no doubt there are tons of examples you can find in books or online

Comment: Do you want to just restrict to the numbers? or one can add special characters as well (Considering them not as alphabets)?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45431798/jcomobox-input-only-characters-no-numbers/) is an example for a JTextField which is used as editor in a combobox, but you can also use this approach for any `JTextField`.

Comment: You can use a `DocumentFilter` to constrain input into a text components

Comment: @akashverma just for the record consider accepting the solution if i solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use JFormattedTextField to achieve this.

```
JTextField text = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());
```